# django populate select list from mysql

Tags: django-views

I am trying to add a select list to my template.  I've been looking at the various questions and have gotten closer, but I can't seem to relate those answers to how I need to modify my view.py.  I started with the Django polls app and have been gradually changing it to test the features of what I want to do.

I added this to models.py:

```
class ftz(models.Model):
    freetradezone = models.IntegerField()
    ftz_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    activeflag = models.CharField(max_length = 1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ftz_text
```

then I changed my template to include this:

Choose a pet:

```
<select id="pet-select">
    {% for entry in items %}
    <option value="{{ ftz.freetradezone }}">{{ ftz.ftz_name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}

</select>
```

pet select was the original hard coded select list which I am now modifying to display the data from my table.

here is my view.py entry

```
class testView(generic.DetailView):
    model = freetradezonedata
    template_name = 'polls/ftz.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
       return freetradezonedata.objects.all()
```

I know I have to add a retrieval of the ftz data and pass it to the template in addition to the data I am already passing.  so far  I haven't been able to find any kind of sample to show me how.

Answer (score 0):

I went away from trying to put a dropdown box on my screen and instead used a listview for ftz(free trade zones), I used that to pull up a listview of divisions for that FTZ.  Not the solution I was looking for but it gives my web app a more modern look instead of emulating how I would do it in .net web forms.